# What permission needs to be added to see the Security folder in Azure SQL?

Tags: permissions, azure-sql-database

[image: My User Does Have the Security Folder]

I have the Security folder, and I am trying to setup other Users with the same permissions that I have.

My User is not the Administrator. Though I was granted all of my permissions (which is about everything) by the Administrator. But this was done months ago and the Administrator (just a dude) does not remember what permissions they gave me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a minimum you need to be a member of `loginmanager` role to see Security folder.

Ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins

> Login managers
>
> The other administrative role is the login manager role. Members of
>   this role can create new logins in the master database. If you wish,
>   you can complete the same steps (create a login and user, and add a
>   user to the loginmanager role) to enable a user to create new logins
>   in the master. Usually logins are not necessary as Microsoft
>   recommends using contained database users, which authenticate at the
>   database-level instead of using users based on logins. For more
>   information, see Contained Database Users - Making Your Database
>   Portable.

Creating a login:

```
    USE [master]
    GO

   CREATE LOGIN [testPerm2] WITH 
   PASSWORD=N'strong PW'
```

Creating a user in master with no other privilege.

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE USER testPerm2
    FOR LOGIN testPerm2
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
GO
```

Now connect using `SSMS` and this is what you see (Notice no security).

[image]

Adding `testPerm2` user to `loginmanager` role.

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'loginmanager', N'testPerm2'
GO
```

Again connect with `SSMS` or refresh your previous connection and now `testPerm2` user can see security tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have been granted db_securityadmin fixed role. The ALTER ANY USER permission may be needed, and that role has that permission.

For more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/security-best-practices-with-contained-databases

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo

SQLCoffee.com

Comment: Even when I am logged in as the administrative user, I cannot add this permission. I get the error saying the role does not exist or I do not have permissions.